# "We will all be a contestant" vs "We will all be contestants"

Tags: singular-vs-plural

There is a TV show in which the participants judge each other.
What is the correct way to express this idea?

1. We will all be both a contestant and on the jury!
2. We will all be both contestants and on the jury!

Which sentence is grammatically correct?

Comment: Why did you make these choices (a contestant vs. contestants)?

Comment: The first form seems to be incorrect for me, but I am not sure.
That's why I am asking this question.

Comment: Difficult to put a hard and fast rule around this, but I'd use 'each' in the singular and 'all' in the plural.

Answer (score 1):

It's often useful when you have a sentence with a conjunction like this to split it into individual sentences taking one "path" or the other.

In this case, this part is fine:

> We will all be on the jury

As is this:

> We will all be contestants

But this has the wrong agreement:

> * We will all be a contestant

The subject is "all of us" ("we .. all"), which is a group of people, so needs a plural agreement.

One alternative is to use "each" instead of all - the subject "each of us" refers to one person at a time, so we can say:

> We will each be a contestant

Note that "on the jury" is neither singular or plural, so this is also fine:

> We will each be on the jury

---

The other thing that makes the sentence slightly awkward is that "to be contestants" and "to be on the jury" are slightly different senses of "to be" - the first describes something we *are*, and the other something that we *do*. It might sound better therefore to give each clause its own verb, even though they're the same word:

> We will all both be contestants and be on the jury

or:

> We will each both be a contestant and be on the jury

Alternatively, you could make the clauses match, either as Brad suggested with "be competing" in place of "be contestants":

> We will all be both competing and on the jury

Or with "judges" instead of "on the jury" (in a legal context, jury members would be "jurors", but it would be unusual to talk about that in a TV show):

> We will all be both contestants and judges

Or using "each":

> We will each be both competing and on the jury

> We will each be both a contestant and a judge

Taking it one step further, we could use "compete" and "judge" as verbs, and dispense with the "be" completely:

> We will all both compete and judge

> We will each both compete and judge

Answer (score 0):

> We will all be both a contestant and on the jury!

sounds fine to me, but although technically correct it is not precise.

> We will all be both contestants and on the jury!

This version I would question as a singular person cannot be multiple contestants

> ***We are all both Judges and Contestants!***

Sounds better to me, it describes exactly what we will be doing. The original sentence was a hybrid, a mixture of what we are in scene one and what we are to be part of in scene two.

Alternatively

> ***We will all be both competing and on the jury***

---

precise [C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/precise)adjective; exact and accurate:

compete; verb; to try to be more successful than someone or something else:

Comment: I'm not convinced by this. "We will all be contestants" and "We will all be on the jury" both sound fine to me, so I see nothing wrong with combining them. Perhaps separating the two verbs would sound a little better, since they're slightly different senses of the same word: "We will all both be contestants, and be on the jury"